# Using Current row value inside a function as a constant SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to run a query where a I have to use the current row as sort of a pivot. As an example:

```
SELECT 
 PERSONID, 
 PERSONAGE AS CURRENTAGE, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN (CURRENTAGE-PERSONAGE) >1 THEN PERSONAGE ELSE NULL END) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONCITY) AS OldestYounger
FROM 
 PERSON;
```

I was wondering if such a thing is possible in DB2 or any database in general, my scenario is much more complex. I am not looking for a workaround solution, just some way of using the current row as a pivot and then partitioning by a common attribute.

I know in this example I could just use `LAG()` and order by AGE, or use `RANK()`.

EDIT:

Expected Result:

```
PersonID|CurrentAge|OldestYounger|City
1        22         18            York
2        25         22            York
3        30         24            Jersey
4        18         NULL          York
5        24         NULL          Jersey
6        7          NULL          Miami
```

When PersonID 2 is selected it should find two younger Persons in the same city, and then get the `MAX()` value. But when performing CurrentAge-PersonAge, it is one and the same and will always return zero. I am looking for a way to make CurrentAge constant for that instance, while looking through the other PersonAge's.

Comment: Hello Sharp welcome to StackOverflow, Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you looking to make this row specifically a pivot or have pivot like properties? Primary and Foreign keys are the common way to do this if you aren't trying to do a one-to-one pivot.

Comment: You may want to show what your expected result might look like, as your explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: Your example does not make sense to me -- `CURRENTAGE-PERSONAGE` will always be 0 since you show above that CURRENTAGE and PERSONAGE are the same thing, unless you are joining these variables from another table or something?

Comment: ...I think we need to see your actual use case, because I'm suspicious about `LAG` not being an option.  I suspect if you restate the "question" in the query, something will fall out - that is instead of doing the math and then getting the max, get the max _first_ (with `UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING` or something), then do the math.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DECLARE @Age as int

SET @Age = SELECT PERSONAGE FROM PERSON WHERE ID=2

SELECT 
 PERSONID, 
 PERSONAGE AS CURRENTAGE, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN (@Age-PERSONAGE) >1 THEN PERSONAGE ELSE NULL END) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONCITY) AS OldestYounger
FROM 
 PERSON
```

This way you have the age of the one user and comparing it to others. What your query is doing now is comparing each user to themselves and ordering by city.

Comment: Since I'm reasonably certain the OP was wanting to get results for _all_ people, using a host variable like this probably won't work (efficiently).  I think the use of `SELECT` is confusing things in the original question.